# Modeling and testing for trends in hospital-surveillance (count, event) data

Tags: bayesian, count-data, trend, frequentist, test-for-trend

## Intro

Hi all, I'm working with hospital-based surveillance data. My peers and I are trained (loosely speaking) as frequentists. I'm mindful of the aphorism:

> Statistics: A subject which most statisticians find difficult but which many physicians are experts on.

... and want to improve through practice.

## Example

Here's a good example.

```
hospitalizations <- structure(list(timespan = structure(1:4, .Label = c("2002-2004", 
"2005-2007", "2008-2010", "2011-2013"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), c(65, 66, 52, 44), c(4417, 4361, 
4458, 4560)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("timespan", 
"count", "pop"))
```

### Trend or No Trend?

In this particular case, I've been advised to rely on `stats::prop.trend.test()`, which exploits the sequencing of the observations, in preference to `prop.test()`.

#### Less power: `prop.test()`

```
> with(hospitalizations, prop.test(count, pop))

    4-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  count out of pop
X-squared = 7.2, df = 3, p-value = 0.07
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
  prop 1   prop 2   prop 3   prop 4 
0.014716 0.015134 0.011664 0.009649
```

#### More power: `prop.trend.test()`

`help(prop.trend.test)` says:

> Performs chi-squared test for trend in proportions, i.e., a test asymptotically optimal for local alternatives where the log odds vary in proportion with `score`. By default, `score` is chosen as the group numbers.

```
> with(hospitalizations, prop.trend.test(count, pop))

    Chi-squared Test for Trend in Proportions

data:  count out of pop ,
 using scores: 1 2 3 4
X-squared = 6.2, df = 1, p-value = 0.01
```

## Doing it Differently

How should I start learning about ways to tackle this question, and related ones, using a different, complementary approach? I'm particularly interested in using this as a jumping-off point into simple Bayesian / MLE techniques.

- For example, suppose I'm willing to start with a prior based on the first two observations, and then update my belief/model according to the next two. How would I implement that in R? Any recommendations for libraries, whitepapers, chapters, books, articles, posts, etc.? (Stan sounds fun.)
- Or, suppose I want to generate a maximum-likelihood estimate of a slope and intercept. I don't know where to start. (I'm an R user, and like to learn from code-based examples.)

I recognize that this is a wide-open question, and you have other jobs to do. Please allow me to thank you in advance for your time and attention. Comments on this specific example (`prop.trend.test()` vs `prop.test()`) are also very welcome.